# How to put JSON data from server into table view cell in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview

I'm trying to display the JSON data from server into table view cell. I'm having problems with capturing the response values. How to get jobTime.count and get jobEndTime value? I want to display jobTime-jobEndTime to each cell.

I think I have to declare a custom struct job. but I'm don't know how to create.

```
struct Job {
    var jobDate: String
    var jobEndTime: Int
    var jobID: Int
    var jobTime: Int

    init(dict: [String:AnyObject]) {
        self.jobDate = dict["jobDate"] as! String
        self.jobEndTime = dict["jobEndTime"] as! Int
        self.jobID = dict["jobID"] as! Int
        self.jobTime = dict["jobTime"] as! Int
    }
}

var jobs = [Job]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    retrieveTime()
}

func retrieveTime(){
    if let crew = user!["crew"] as? [String:Any], let crewID = crew["crew_id"] as? String{

        let param = ["action": "retrieve time", "job": ["crew_id": crewID, "jobDate": passedData]] as [String : Any]

        let headers = [
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        ]

        if let postData = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])) {

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://52.221.231.3/gv/app_api.php")!,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = postData

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                (data, response, error) -> Void in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        let result = json["result"] as? String

                        if (result == "success") {

                            if let jsonData = json["jobs"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                                self.jobs = jsonData.map { Job(dict: $0) }
                            }
                                print(self.jobs)
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }else{
                            print(result!)

                        }
                    }
                })
            }

            task.resume()
        }

    }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return jobs.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "jobCell", for: indexPath)
    let job = self.jobs[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = job.jobDate

    return cell
}
```

Sorry about the messy code, this is my 1st time working with JSON in Swift.

```
JSON Data :

    {
    jobs = (
        {
            jobDate = "2017-09-07";
            jobEndTime = 1504749600;
            jobID = 104;
            jobTime = 1504746000;
        },
                {
            jobDate = "2017-09-07";
            jobEndTime = 1504756800;
            jobID = 105;
            jobTime = 1504753200;
        }
    );
    message = "Retrieve Sucessfully";
    result = success;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your JSON output?

Comment: First of all, dont put your tableview.reload() in the viewDidLoad, put inside your URLSession callback after all process, so it will run after you receive the data.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question.

Comment: store json data into array of objects and in tableView function, process this array

Comment: ok.. I updated the question. I tried to store it. I got "Could not cast value of type"

Comment: runtime erro? which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion, Alamofire is a good framework for sending networking requests and it is found [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

Also, for working with JSON, Swift is not that good. You have to write a lot of extra code for it. A popular library for dealing with JSON is called SwiftyJSON and it works with Alamofire really nicely and it's found [here](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

This will allow you to write requests with JSON responses like this:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in

    switch response.result {

    case .success(let value):

        let json = JSON(value)

        let name = json["name"].stringValue
        let job = json["teacher"].stringValue

    case .failure(let error):

        print(error)
    }
}
```

The SwiftyJSON readme file includes information on how to loop through JSON results which you will need to do.

Comment: Just use JSONSerialization. No need to use another framework. It looks short, but you haven't done any error checking, and haven't stored the results anywhere.